# Optimising regex for matching domain name in url

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a regex that matches iframe urls, and captures various components. The regex is given below

```
/(<iframe.*?src=['|"])((?:https?:\/\/|\/\/)[^\/]*)(?:.*?)(['|"][^>]*some-token:)([a-zA-Z0-9]+)(.*?>)/igm
```

To be clear my actual requirement is to transforms in a html string, such strings

```
<iframe src="http://somehost.com/somepath1/path2" class="some-token:abc123">
```

to

```
<iframe src="http://somehost.com/newpath?token=abc123" class="some-token:abc123">
```

The regex works as it is supposed to be, but for normal length html, it takes around 2 seconds to execute, which i think is very, high.

I would really appreciate if someone could point me how to optimise this regex, i am sure i am doing something terribly wrong, because before i used this regex

```
/(<iframe.*?src=['|"])(?:.*?)(['|"][^>]*some-token:)([a-zA-Z0-9]+)(.*?>)/igm
```

to completely replace the source url and just add the paramter, it was taking just 100 ms

Comment: Means you need to change only value of "src"?

Comment: Try `/(<iframe\b[^<]*\bsrc=['"])[\s\S]*?(['"][^<]*-token:)([a-zA-Z0-9]+)([^<]*>)/igm` or perhaps, use a DOM parser.

Comment: JavaScript in browser comes with the DOM. Use it to pick out the href and class, then you can use regex all you want to modify the URL.

Comment: It these answers helped you, accept one of them.

Comment: this transformation needs to happen in server (node.js) the reason why i am forced to use regex instead of DOM

Comment: i don't understand why this question has a negative vote, it is a legitimate question about how to optimise the regex, is it not ?

Answer (score 3):

You do not need to (and should not) parse the `iframe` element as a string; you just need to access its attributes, and retrieve information from them and rewrite them.

```
function fix_iframe_src(iframe) {
    var src = iframe.getAttribute('src');
    var klass = iframe.getAttribute('class');

    var token = get_token(klass);
    src = fix_src(src, token);
    iframe.setAttribute('src', src);
}
```

Writing `get_token` and `fix_src` are left as an exercise.

If you want to find a bunch of iframes and fix them all up, then

```
var iframes = document.querySelectorAll('iframe');
for (var i = 0; i < iframes.length; i++) {
  fix_iframe_src(iframes[i]);
}
```

By the way, the value of your `class` attribute seems to be broken. I doubt if it will match any CSS rules, if that's the intent. Are you using it for something other than to provide the token? In that case, you would be best off using a data attribute such as `data-token`.

Minor point about regexp flags: the `g` and `m` flags are going to do nothing for you. `m` is about matching anchors like `^` and `$` to the beginning and end of lines within the source string, which is not an issue for you. `g` is about matching multiple times, which is also not an issue.

The reason your regexp is taking so long is most likely that you are throwing the entire DOM at it. Hard to tell unless you show us the code from which you are calling it.

Comment: I fail to see where catastrophic backtracking comes into play, here. There's backtracking potential but nothing on the order of catastrophic, at least from my glance.

Comment: @iismathwizard You're right. Fixed my answer with a different theory.

Comment: @torazaburo i am doing this in node.js environment hence i am not using the browser DOM api. The strings are huge often, entire html source string. But as i shared about the previous functionality i was using, just replacing entire url on same length html strings used to take much less.